# ev_loop does not continue after asyncio.sleep

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I have a program with 2 main tasks. These tasks do some stuff on a website and check a counter when they are done. The task should wait until the timer hits 0 and then start over. This should go on forever.

I get the console output that the task is sleeping for the duration of the counter, but after it is done the task does not get restarted.

Could it be that `await asyncio.wait(tasks)` waits until all the `asyncio.sleep` of all the tasks are done? If so how can I make it the task get restarted after its own counter hits 0?

**main.py**

```
async def loop_executer(loop):

    while loop.is_running():
        tasks = []
        for id in ids:
            t1 = Task_1(id)
            t2 = Task_2(id)

            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(t1.do_stuff1()))
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(t2.do_stuff2()))
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)


ev_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ev_loop.create_task(loop_executer(ev_loop))
ev_loop.run_forever()
```

**task_1 class**

```
async def task1(self):
    
    *DO SOME STUFF*

    sleep_time = get_counter(self)
    print("waiting {} seconds".format(sleep_time))
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print("DONE!!!! NO MORE SLEEPING!")
```

**task_2 class**

```
async def task2(self):
    
    *DO SOME OTHER STUFF*

    sleep_time = get_counter(self)
    print("waiting {} seconds".format(sleep_time))
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print("DONE!!!! NO MORE SLEEPING!")
```

Comment: I'll probably will have to use `asyncio.Queue`